# http.createserver and net.createserver in node.js together

Tags: javascript, httpserver

I have 2 scripts in node js. One uses 'http' and other uses 'net'. I want to make these scripts together in one script. My 'http' script are as below:

```
const http = require('http');
const hostname = 'localhost';
const port = 3000;
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
 console.log(req.headers);
 res.statusCode = 200;
 res.end('<html><body><h1>Hello, World!</h1></body></html>');
})
server.listen(port, hostname);
```

'net' script:

```
var net = require('net');

var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(4352, 'x.x.x.x', function() {
    console.log('Connected');
    client.write('%1POWR 1\r\n');
});

client.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('Received: ' + data);
    client.destroy(); // kill client after server's response
});

client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed');
});
```

**My purpose is to run the 'net' script once I start the 'http' script.**

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the whole `net script` in a exported function:

```
var net = require('net');

module.exports = () => {
    var client = new net.Socket();
    client.connect(4352, 'x.x.x.x', function() {
        console.log('Connected');
        client.write('%1POWR 1\r\n');
    });
    
    client.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('Received: ' + data);
        client.destroy(); // kill client after server's response
    });
    
    client.on('close', function() {
        console.log('Connection closed');
    });
}
```

Import and execute the exported function in `http script`:

```
const http = require('http');
const hostname = 'localhost';
const port = 3000;
require('path/to/net/script')() //Add to anywhere you like
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
 console.log(req.headers);
 res.statusCode = 200;
 res.end('<html><body><h1>Hello, World!</h1></body></html>');
})
server.listen(port, hostname);
```